# SSL Certificate failed install in IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7, ssl, ssl-certificate

I can't seem to install my SSL in IIS7 because when I do it appears in the Server Certificates list but then if I navigate away from that page or refresh it then it disappears?

I don't know if it has anything to do with my recent re-installation of the OS on the Server. Do I need to request and new crt file from my CA and run through the CSR process again or can I use the crt file I backed up before the re-install?

Answer (score 1):

You need both the public certificate and the private key that matches the certificate. You may be able to recover the private key using the steps outlined on [this page](http://www.entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=7905).

If you've lost the private key, the public certificate is worthless; your certificate provider may allow you to reissue the certificate for free. You'll need to generate a new CSR (which will also generate a corresponding private key) in order to have the key reissued.